# SQLite (1) no such table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I run my android app I keep getting the error (1) no such table userTable, as far as I am aware I am creating the table  in

```
TABLE_CREATE = "create table userTable("    
                + USER + " text not null, "  + PWD + " text not null, );";
```

I have two other databases in this project and the are working fine, any help is welcome.

```
package com.weightpro.db;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class usrPwdDB {

public static final String USER = "userName";
public static final String PWD = "password";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "userTable";
public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "userdatabase";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table userTable("    
            + USER + " text not null, "  + PWD + " text not null, );"; 

DBHelper WDBHelper;
Context mContext;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public usrPwdDB(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    WDBHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);

}

 private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
 {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATA_BASE_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try{
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }

        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS userTable");
        onCreate(db);
    }


 }
public usrPwdDB open()
{
    db = WDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close(){
    WDBHelper.close();
}

public long insertInfo(String userName, String password){
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put(USER, userName);
    content.put(PWD, password);
    return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
}

public boolean getUserNameAndPassword(String userName, String Password) throws SQLException {

            Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {USER,
                    PWD},USER+"='"+userName+"' AND password='"+Password+"'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;}

public Cursor returnData(){
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {USER, PWD},null,null,null,null,null);
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE)` throw an SQLException when the create statement is wrong?

Comment: @Ridcully Yes and OP is catching exceptions in `onCreate()` and thus hiding the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the last comma `,` from the create table syntax,

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = 
    "create table userTable("    
    + USER + " text not null, "  
    + PWD + " text not null, );";    // remove this comma after not null
```

The correct syntax should be

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = 
    "create table userTable("    
    + USER + " text not null, "  
    + PWD + " text not null );";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, changed it to but still the same error:
 private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table userTable(" 
          + USER + " text not null, "  + PWD + " text not null );";

Comment: This is probably the right answer, which teaches you in the future to use the catch clause to actually notify yourself or the user that an error occurred or if you're gonna go with the print stack trace approach, you should look at it :)

Comment: @user3535757, Still you havent accept any answer of your question. Let me guide you how to accept answer. Once you get the answers from the others, you should tick the answer ( there is tick mark besides the each answer ), which suits best for your question.

Comment: @user3535757 can you paste the code of other table's create table syntax ?

Comment: pasted below:
 
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table      weightable(weight text not null);";

 public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table weightstable(exercise text not null, reps text not null, weight text not null);";

Comment: I guess something wrong. what is the class file names ?

Comment: can you please tell me the class names where are you creating these two other tables/database  ?

Comment: the other class names are:
personalWDB
WeightsDB

Comment: @user3535757, can you join me in this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52179/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-sandeep-v ?

Answer (score 2):

You go wrong over here

```
 + USER + " text not null, "  + PWD + " text not null, );"; //remove , from last text not null
```

correct `SQL command` with below

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table userTable("    
        + USER + " text not null, "  + PWD + " text not null);" ;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, changed it to but still the same error:
 private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table userTable(" 
          + USER + " text not null, "  + PWD + " text not null );";

Comment: you probably uninstall your app and again install so that New DB is created.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge but how would I do this?

Comment: first remove your app from your device `go to settings->Application manager-->select your app-->uninstall` and then run(install) again

Comment: Since table has not created, I dont thin he need to uninstall the application.

Comment: @Kedarnath but after our answer he faced the same issue. what you probably suggest for that?

Comment: un-installed app and same problem!

This is very strange as the other two databases work fine, any other suggestions?

Comment: @user3535757 which other two database you are talking about ?

Comment: I have two other databases in my project, which are set up pretty much identically to this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table userTable("    
        + USER + " text not null, "  + PWD + " text not null,);" ;
```

remove  "," after "text not null" and also remove ";"(semicolon) in the string, that is not needed i think,

then clear data or uninstall application then execute again

even though the creation of table failed i think next time onCreate() in SQLiteOpenHelper only executes once, so you will need to clear data of application

if you are using separate class for separate table and using same DB name, then all the tables in the first using class will be ok, and others will not be created since for a single database onCreate() function works only one, even if there is separate classes each with onCreate(),

onCreate() function creates a file in DB location of android file system when first called onCreate(), if the onCreate called again it check for the existence of DBNAME file in DB location and avoid creating if its exit, I think this is logic behind it...

so keep one onCreate() function for a single DB file and create all tables in that function

Comment: Changed to below and it didn't work

private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table userTable("    
        + USER + " text not null "  + PWD + " text not null)" ;

Comment: clear data or uninstall application then execute again

Comment: did that as well but no luck

Comment: you are using seperate classes for seperate tables,right?